# octopress (ruby on rails) stripe integration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments, octopress

I would like to integrate stripe payment system to my octopress blog. The problem is that octopress is used to build static web sites, and integration stripe requires to add new Controllers  (dynamic) to handle user payments.
how can I add such a controller without breaking the octopress file structure.

regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with octopress. But I'm assuming it's similar to Wordpress, and whenever I want to use rails functionality on a wordpress application, I create a subdomain that points to my rails app using a service like `dnsimple`.

So if someone visits `railsapp.mywebsiteurl.com` they will receive a response from my rails application. However, if someone visits `www.mywebsiteurl.com` they will get a response from octopress.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This can be a good solution. but you need to settup a subdomain for the rails app. Do you have to pay additional fees to your domain name Host to get such a subdomain?

Comment: Correct. You'll have to check with your hosting. I used webfaction and they didn't charge anything extra. Now I use dnsimple and heroku to setup my sub domains. I pay like $5 a month to dnsimple.

Comment: I am also using heroku for the rails app and the octopress blog. I think I will try this option first and setup a sub domain as suggested. Thank you!

Comment: Do you have a live example of your wordpress site with rails app in a sub domain?

Comment: Sure. statistics.neobux.reviews